# If $b|a$ and $f$ is a completely multiplicative function, how can I show that $f(a/b) = f(a) / f(b)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multiplicative-function

I know that $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$ , but I'm not quite sure how to use this information.

Comment: name $c=a/b,$  then $a=bc.$  The question in the title becomes $f(c) = f(bc) / f(b) ?  $

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$f(a/b)f(b)=f(a)$ from the multiplicative property of the function. Thus, $f(a/b)=f(a)/f(b)$.